# Difference between constant curvature kinematics and rigid link kinematics

Tags: kinematics

What is the difference between constant curvature kinematics and rigid link kinematics and what is their respective definition?

Comment: The question was edited, a definition of the kinematics problem (not a kinematic structure) has been removed, since it offered no context to the question formulated after the verbatim copy of the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigid link kinematics assumes that the robot is made of rigid structural elements connected by pivot or sliding joints, and describes the locations of points on the robot (or more generally, the locations and orientations of frames attached to the robot) as a function of the joint angles.

Constant-curvature kinematics assumes that the robot is made up of a series of segments that can bend into constant-curvature (i.e., circular) arcs, and describes the locations of points (or locations and orientations of frames) as a function of the segment curvatures.